# vector struct in vector struct in

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Whats wrong in this code?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct {
    float x, y, z;
} aaa;

typedef struct {
    float r, g, b;
    std::vector<aaa> a;
} bbb;

typedef struct {
    float s, t, p;
    std::vector<bbb> b;
} ccc;

int main()
{
    aaa o;
    std::vector<ccc> c;

    c.resize(1); // its OK

    c[0].b.resize(4); // its OK

    c[0].b[0].a.resize(2); // ??? its allocate 4 instead of 2 but why?
    c[0].b[1].a.resize(2); // its OK
    c[0].b[2].a.resize(2); // its OK
    c[0].b[3].a.resize(2); // its OK

    o.x = 1.0f;
    o.y = 0.5f;
    o.z = 2.567f;
    c[0].b[0].a.push_back(o);
    
    o.x = 0.0f;
    o.y = 3.4f;
    o.z = 3.67f;
    c[0].b[0].a.push_back(o);
    
    std::cout << c[0].b[0].a[0].x << std::endl;
    std::cout << c[0].b[0].a[0].y << std::endl;
    std::cout << c[0].b[0].a[0].z << std::endl;

    std::cout << c[0].b[0].a[1].x << std:: endl;
    std::cout << c[0].b[0].a[1].y << std::endl;
    std::cout << c[0].b[0].a[1].z << std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

And here is watch window output:

> ```
> vector c: size = 1; // its OK
>
> vector b: size = 4; // its OK
>
> vector a[0]: size = 4; // ??? (4) ???
>
> vector a[1]: size = 2; // its OK
>
> vector a[3]: size = 2; // its OK
>
> vector a[4]: size = 2; // its OK
> ```

Comment: Not sure I'd trust the watch window. Have you tried just printing out the vector size after each resize?

Comment: @ closevoter: this is pretty much a perfect testcase.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::vector::resize()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) resizes the vector. So you resize it to 2, and then add 2 more items (with `push_back()`), so your size is 4.

As mentioned in the comments, if you use

```
std::cout << "c[0].b[0].a.size() = " << c[0].b[0].a.size() << std::endl;
```

at different points in the code, you will see the the appropriate sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Member function `resize` creates new elements if the current size of a vector is less than the size specified in resize().

Member function `push_back` appends new elements to the vector.

So after statement

```
c[0].b[0].a.resize(2);
```

vector a will have two elements. And after these two statements

```
   c[0].b[0].a.push_back(o);
   //...
   c[0].b[0].a.push_back(o);
```

it will be appended with another two new elements. Thus as a result vector a will have 4 elements.

If you want to have only two elements then you have to write the following instead of using function push_back

```
   c[0].b[0].a[0] = o;
   //...
   c[0].b[0].a[1] = o;
```